# Vagrant up returns error

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant-windows

**Operating System**

Windows 10 Home 64-bit

**Versions**

Vagrant 2.1.2

VirtualBox 5.2.18 r124319

**Problem**

I am trying to setup a Vagrant environment on a Windows 10 workstation so an existing Ruby on Rails project may be developed on it. Git, Vagrant, and VirtualBox installed without problems. The project has been cloned to a working directory, the Vagrantfile was included in the project by the project leader.

I open Powershell and navigate to the working directory. I run `vagrant up`. Vagrant appears to attempt an install of the vagrant-vbguest plugin four times and throws an error.

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:47:in `[]=': Invalid argument - ruby_setenv(VAGRANT_NO_PLUGINS) (Errno::EINVAL)
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:47:in `block in <main>'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:36:in `each_index'
from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.1.2/gems/vagrant-2.1.2/bin/vagrant:36:in `<main>'
```

**Vagrantfile**
https://gist.github.com/Tanoro/05cae2eba90cffcb6c12e923012f812a

**Screenshot**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/G730G.jpg

**Debug Output**
https://gist.github.com/Tanoro/e0b97ff114ee80faad5a8b65f6edadd7

**Fixes already tried**

1. https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/pull/8127
2. https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9577#issuecomment-408621009

Comment: How is this a windows or powershell question? and why are you on Home edition?

Comment: The employer provided the workstation, not me. That is what I have to work with. If it can be done, I need direction. If it can't, I'll send that word up the chain.

As for the tags, that is my error. I was using them to define what I was working with rather than attempting to define the root of the problem. A moderator appears to have fixed it.

Comment: Using a home license for professional use sounds like a licensing violation I wouldn't want to be involved in.  I'm not even sure it supports virtualization.

Comment: Windows 10 Home does support virtualization using 3rd party apps like VirtualBox. As for the licensing issue, I'll alert my supervisor and suggest getting the Pro version. In the meantime, assistance with this error would be appreciated.

Comment: `'[]=': Invalid argument - ruby_setenv(VAGRANT_NO_PLUGINS) (Errno::EINVAL)` looks like an argument isn't being passed correctly.

Comment: I notified my supervisor on that licensing issue. Microsoft has consistently weighed in that using the home version for business use is permitted "if it meets your needs." That is to say certain functions are disabled in the home version. Whether or not this issue is being caused by a home edition disability remains to be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply on Github on this issue.
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10134

I opened the `bin/vagrant` file and stubbed the `vagrantfile_name` option on line 47 as instructed here.
https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/pull/10030/commits/9321f3cb6cbac452e0b7c3a9d1f9731446c60f75

I navigated OUTSIDE of my project directory and manually installed the plugin I needed: `vagrant-vbguest`. It successfully installed. I navigated back into my project directory and tried `vagrant up` again, which succeeded.

I am told this behavior will be fixed in the Vagrant's next release.